# Gerar um alerta, quando o valor que está no input for maior que um valor fixo em javascript

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Eae galera!

Seguinte, estou passando por uma dificuldade, estou tentando gerar um código que gere um alerta, quando o valor que está dentro do input (que muda constantemente de forma automática), for maior ou menos que um valor fixo. Estou tentando fazer em javascript. A única coisa que saiu foi isso:

```
var valorAtual = document.querySelector('#amountOut') // input onde está o valor que muda constantemente 
valorAtual.addEventListener('change',(e) => { 
    if (valorAtual.value >= 0.4915 ) {
        alert('VENDER');
    }
});
```

Basicamente a função que eu quero gerar nesse código, é relacionado a um valor de um token (criptomoeda), que como o valor do token é mudado diversas vezes a cada minuto, estou querendo implementar, para quando o valor do token for maior que um valor que eu quero, gere esse alerta para mim.

Poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: if (Number(valorAtual.value) ...

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, o principal ponto da sua questão é: Gerar o alerta automaticamente quando o valor é atualizado. Isso já inviabiliza o uso do atributo `"onchange"` dos campos `<input>`, que limita o disparo do evento à modificações feitas pelos usuários e não geradas automaticamente.

Como você não forneceu detalhes de onde esse valor da criptomoeda vem e como é atualizado, simulei a modificação automática através do método `setInterval()`, uma vez a cada 5 segundos e utilizei números gerados aleatoriamente entre 0 e 1. E o resultado foi exatamente a solução para o que questionou.

```
var valorAtual = document.querySelector('#amountOut') // input onde está o valor que muda constantemente 

function myFunction() {
    if (valorAtual.value >= 0.4915 ) {
        alert('VENDER');
    }
}

setInterval(() => {
    valorAtual.value = Math.random();
    myFunction()
}, 5000);
```

Uma segunda opção é caso você esteja utilizando alguma API. Novamente, este é um cenário de simulação. Neste caso, supondo que o retorno da requisição seja um JSON equivalente a:

```
{
    "value": 5
}
```

O disparo do alerta deve ser feito depois do tratamento da resposta obtida. Exemplo simples neste cenário:

```
var valorAtual = document.querySelector('#amountOut') // input onde está o valor que muda constantemente 

function myFunction() {
    if (valorAtual.value >= 0.4915 ) {
        alert('VENDER');
    }
}

fetch('https://api.foo.com/')
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then((data) => {
    valorAtual.value = data.value
    myFunction();
})
```

**Conclusão**: A maneira como o alerta é gerado, vai depender de como os dados são atualizados, mas em situações como essa, infelizmente não será possível realizar o disparo através do listener de eventos. Este deve ser utilizado apenas quando o disparo do evento for condicionado à interação do usuário.